# How can I append additional dictionary to my model_list?

Tags: python, django

I get `'Pixel' object does not support item assignment`

How can I append additional dictionary to my pixel_list objects?

```
def pixel_main(request, page):
    y = int(page) * 10
    x = y - 10
    pixel_list = Pixel.objects.all()[x:y]
    for i in pixel_list:
        if Handler.objects.filter(pixel=i.id).filter(user=request.user):
            i['vote'] = True
        else:
            i['vote'] = False

    return render_to_response('pixel_main.html', {"pixels": pixel_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Why not just use an attribute?

Comment: Because I am not advanced in any type of programming.

Comment: ... But you are already using an (already-existing) attribute when you write things like `Pixel.objects`. :/

Comment: Yes. Pixel class is existing in my mysql tables. But now, when i add attribute "vote=models.BooleanField(default=False)" and do things like Michał Modzelewski wrote it works good. Do You know that it will be possible even if Pixel will be not have "vote" attribute? I am asking because my server using strange things for python/django and I can't configure it to use shell :/

Comment: Yes, like Michał's answer says, you may just add the attribute to the Pixels when you want to. But it is usually better to set them up in the `__init__` method, to keep organized. Your tools for saving to the SQL tables might have some other requirements, too... please check the documentation.

Comment: I will check documentation. I start learning python from documentation. I thining that django documentation will be enought but i see that i don't have some basic knowlage in python and that hole brings me problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python lets you add attributes to object instances using dot notation:

```
for i in pixel_list:
    if Handler.objects.filter(pixel=i.id).filter(user=request.user):
        i.vote = True
    else:
        i.vote = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) to the pixel class in your `models.py`, if the `vote` should be saved.

Alternatively, you can pass the votes to the view in a separate object:

```
vote = defaultdict(bool)
if Handler.objects.filter(pixel=i.id).filter(user=request.user):
    vote[i] = True
```

Comment: @cris: yes, but please check my updated answer for a perhaps more elegant solution.

Comment: It look nice. I want to check this in practice but my service is very slow today :/

Comment: @Cris, `from collections import defaultdict`